# Games are randomly freezing

Tags: graphics, games, steam

All the Steam games I tried to play freeze at random times. I tried to play them with and without Steam. I also noticed that notifications (Steam or Unity/Ubuntu) always cause a freeze, so I made sure to prevent them, but they are still freezing randomly.

During the search for a solution I read about some people with similar issues and most/many of them had Intel graphics cards. None of the suggested solutions worked for me so far.

It's only games I have this issues with, not with any other applications.

By the way, because "Additional Drivers" are often suggested. That window looks like this for me:

[image]

System:

- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 64-bit
- Intel Core i5-5200U CPU
- Intel HD Graphics 5500
- 8GB RAM

Games I tried: Darkest Dungeon, Rimworld, Europa Universalis IV, Invisible, Inc., ...

Edit: Turning "Unredirect Fullscreen Windows" off with CompizConfig Settings Manager appears to fix this issue. However, this is not a real solution to the problem, because it leads to a huge drop in performance when gaming.